# Actual and formal argument lists differ in length error in main

Tags: java, text, import

Im working on a project where I have 3 text files with data of doctors, patients and home visits. When Im trying to upload the doctors file, upload all the data to a new object I get an error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Id_pacjenta  Nazwisko    Imie    PESEL   Data_urodzenia"
at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:68)
at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:658)
at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:776)
at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:40)

Below I'll paste my main as well as the classes & a snapshot of the text file used for imports:

Could anyone advise how to avoid this issue? Thanks!

```
 public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Lekarz> lekarz = new ArrayList<>();

        try{
            File fileLekarze = new File("src/com/company/lekarze.txt");
            Scanner readerLekarze = new Scanner(fileLekarze);
            while(readerLekarze.hasNextLine()){
                String[] data =readerLekarze.nextLine().split(" ");
                lekarz.add(new Lekarz(Integer.parseInt(data[0]),data[1],data[2],data[3],new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(data[4]),data[5],data[6]));
            }
            readerLekarze.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Error File Lekarze");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        List<Pacjenci> pacjent = new ArrayList<>();

        try{
            File pacjenciFile = new File("src/com/company/pacjenci.txt");
            Scanner readerPacjenci = new Scanner(pacjenciFile);
            while(readerPacjenci.hasNextLine()){
                String[] data = readerPacjenci.nextLine().split(" ");
                pacjent.add(new Pacjenci(Integer.parseInt(data[0]),data[1],data[2],data[3],new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(data[4])));
            }
            readerPacjenci.close();

        }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Error File Pacjenci");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}

    public class Pacjenci {

    private int idPacjenta;
    private String nazwisko;
    private String imie;
    private String pesel;
    private Date dataUrodzenia;

    public Pacjenci(int idPacjenta, String nazwisko, String imie, String pesel, Date dataUrodzenia) {
        this.idPacjenta = idPacjenta;
        this.nazwisko = nazwisko;
        this.imie = imie;
        this.pesel = pesel;
        this.dataUrodzenia = dataUrodzenia;

    }

    public int getIdPacjenta() {
        return idPacjenta;
    }

    public void setIdPacjenta(int idPacjenta) {
        this.idPacjenta = idPacjenta;
    }

    public String getNazwisko() {
        return nazwisko;
    }

    public void setNazwisko(String nazwisko) {
        this.nazwisko = nazwisko;
    }

    public String getImie() {
        return imie;
    }

    public void setImie(String imie) {
        this.imie = imie;
    }

    public String getPesel() {
        return pesel;
    }

    public void setPesel(String pesel) {
        this.pesel = pesel;
    }

    public Date getDataUrodzenia() {
        return dataUrodzenia;
    }

    public void setDataUrodzenia(Date dataUrodzenia) {
        this.dataUrodzenia = dataUrodzenia;
    }
    

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Pacjenci{" +
                "idPacjenta=" + idPacjenta +
                ", nazwisko='" + nazwisko + '\'' +
                ", imie='" + imie + '\'' +
                ", pesel='" + pesel + '\'' +
                ", dataUrodzenia=" + dataUrodzenia +
                ", wizyty=" +
                ", lekarze=" +
                '}';
    }
}

public class Wizyty {
    private Lekarz idLekarza;
    private Pacjenci idPacjenta;
    private Date dataWizyty;

    public Wizyty(Lekarz idLekarza, Pacjenci idPacjenta, Date dataWizyty) {
        this.idLekarza = idLekarza;
        this.idPacjenta = idPacjenta;
        this.dataWizyty = dataWizyty;
    }

    public Lekarz getIdLekarza() {
        return idLekarza;
    }

    public void setIdLekarza(Lekarz idLekarza) {
        this.idLekarza = idLekarza;
    }

    public Pacjenci getIdPacjenta() {
        return idPacjenta;
    }

    public void setIdPacjenta(Pacjenci idPacjenta) {
        this.idPacjenta = idPacjenta;
    }

    public Date getDataWizyty() {
        return dataWizyty;
    }

    public void setDataWizyty(Date dataWizyty) {
        this.dataWizyty = dataWizyty;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Wizyty{" +
                "idLekarza=" + idLekarza +
                ", idPacjenta=" + idPacjenta +
                ", dataWizyty=" + dataWizyty +
                '}';
    }
}



     Id_pacjenta    Nazwisko    Imie    PESEL   Data_urodzenia
             100       Kowal    Waldemar 01211309876    2001-1-13
```

Comment: You are only passing one parameter to your constructor: `new Lekarz(Integer.parseInt(data[0]))`

Comment: Ok so if I were to delete the Lists from the constructor and leave it as it is in the file I get an error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Id_pacjenta Nazwisko Imie PESEL Data_urodzenia"
 at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:68)
 at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:658)
 at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:776)
 at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:40)

Comment: Please edit your question to show the actual code that is producing that error.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the data spacing in the file, try this:

```
while(readerLekarze.hasNextLine()){
     String line = readerLekarze.nextLine();
     // Remove leading and trailing whitespaces (if any).
     line = line.trim()
     // "\\s+" Takes care of any multi-spacing within the data line when splitting.  
     String[] data =line.split("\\s+"); 
     lekarz.add(new Lekarz(Integer.parseInt(data[0]),data[1],data[2],data[3],new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(data[4]),data[5],data[6]));
}
```

You **could** also just do:

```
String[] data = readerLekarze.nextLine().trim().split("\\s+");
```

Comment: There is still an error in this line: `pacjent.add(new Pacjenci(Integer.parseInt(data[0]), data[1], data[2], data[3], new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(data[4]))); ` which is line 44. With this Exception message: 
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "100 Kowal Waldemar 01211309876 2001-1-13"
 at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:68)
 at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:658)
 at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:776)
 at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:44)`

Comment: Show me what you are using to Split the data line. I sure hope it isn't `" "`. Do it the way I show in my example code. After the line is split apply this line of code: `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data));`. What do you see as an array?

Comment: I believe your file is TAB delimited and splitting with `" "` just won't do it. If you use `"\\s+"` for your `split()` method (as shown) then it will also split on Tabs and spaces (even if they are multi). If for some reason you can't use Regular Expressions then try `split("\t")`

Comment: Its currently looking like this

`try {
            File fileLekarze = new File("src/com/company/lekarze.txt");
            Scanner readerLekarze = new Scanner(fileLekarze);
            while (readerLekarze.hasNextLine()) {
                String[] data = readerLekarze.nextLine().split("/t");
                lekarz.add(new Lekarz(Integer.parseInt(data[0]), data[1], data[2], data[3], new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(data[4]), data[5], data[6]));
            }
            readerLekarze.close();`

The error is remaining the same. I am using ArrayList

Comment: `"/t"` splits on those literal characters. To split on each tab character you need `"\t"`

Answer (score 0):

As a complement to the @DevilsHnd, you only need to add a code to avoid the first line, because the first line is the "header information" of your file.

```
boolean headerRead = false;
while(readerLekarze.hasNextLine()) {
    if (!headerRead) {
        // extract the first line -> Id_pacjenta    Nazwisko    Imie    PESEL   Data_urodzenia
        readerLekarze.nextLine();
        headerRead = true;
        continue;
    }

    String line = readerLekarze.nextLine();
    // Remove leading and trailing whitespaces (if any).
    line = line.trim();
    // "\\s+" Takes care of any multi-spacing within the data line when splitting.
    String[] data =line.split("\\s+");

    lekarz.add(new Lekarz(
            Integer.parseInt(data[0]),
            data[1],
            data[2],
            data[3],
            new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(data[4])));
}
```